# Apache password protected directory misconfiguration

Tags: apache, joomla, password-protection

i know that there are many posts about that topic but none seems to solve my problem.
My problem is the following, in windows server i have set up Apache, and **i want to make ONLY password protected the directory** **C:/apache/htdocs/j30/administrator** so in the **httpd.conf** below the

```
  <Directory "C:/apache/htdocs">    
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks   
  AllowOverride none    
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

i have add the following

```
  <Directory "C:/apache/htdocs/j30/administrator">
   AllowOverride AuthConfig 
   Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

i have created the passwd.txt using cmd and putted in the  **C:/apache/bin/passwd.txt** and then i have created the **.htaccess** with the following

```
 AuthUserFile "C:/apache/bin/passwd.txt"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "This is Administrator Area"
 Require valid-user
```

and i have putted the **.htaccess** in the **C:/apache/htdocs/j30/administrator**.
The site is a joomla site so i just want only in the administrator area to make password protection in the live site no.

**So everything is working fine except that when browsing for example in localhost in the following url (were the front site stands)
http://localhost/j30
 i still get a username password asking window ??? why ?? what i m doing wrong ??and i m able to browse if i close this window... but then appears again..
**Bear in mind that is working fine the username password window in the**
**http://localhost/j30/administrator**

I just want to have the username password asking window only in

**http://localhost/j30/administrator**

**and not to the**

**http://localhost/j30/**

I hope that u understand this problem, is a misconfiguration in  **httpd.conf** somewere else ??
Please some help guys cause i m really stack here..
Any help would be really appreciated,

Thank you in advance.